# Web2py authentication with a custom domain on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, ssl, web2py

Google App Engine doesn't support SSL for custom domains. Does this mean that it's impossible to host a web2py application on GAE with a custom domain and still be able to use web2py authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can use it, but it just won't be as secure as it should. Of course you could limit yourself to the appspot.com subdomain and have HTTPS there, but that's rather impractical.

GAE team has had the SSL for custom domain on the roadmap now for several years and there is even a closed beta running, but good luck getting into it.

People have cooked up two ways to get around this limitation:

1. Use a reverse proxy with SSL: [here's a good write up on this](http://radomirml.com/2011/01/30/reverse-proxy-for-gae-application-using-nginx-and-ssl).
2. Use CloudFlare for SSL (similar to reverse proxy, but CloudFlare is doing the heavy lifting): [here's the write up](http://blorn.com/post/20185054195/ssl-for-your-domain-on-google-app-engine).

Comment: @Sologub- thanks for this. Of course a hosting service loses its shine when you need to route it through proxies to get it to work for you. Going to Rackspace...

Comment: @Yarin, it all depends on what you are looking for. GAE is a full stack service that provides everything from webserver to database, queues, etc. For my current projects, it would take me days of hard work to just get going on a vps (usually I use linode), not to mention having to make sure it all stays up. With GAE, you follow a few conventions and work around some constraints, then drop in the code, and you are ready to go and scale if the project succeeds. The price for it is some lack of flexibility and a few missing features.